# Nginx to execute php script as different user

Tags: php, nginx

I have written a simple php script to monitor the GPU temperature of my Raspberry. Problem is that this script needs to be run from a user belonging to “video” group.

As we know, nginx runs as www-data user and group and therefore the script does not work.

I would not like to add user www-data to group video.

How can I make nginx execute a script as a different group?

Thnaks,
Daniele

Comment: Perhaps https://serverfault.com/questions/433265/how-do-i-change-the-nginx-user would help.

Comment: If you want to separate these completely then you could use a work queue where nginx adds jobs to the queue and a separate process running with a user in the video group executes the jobs. You don't have to use elaborate stuff for this (message queues etc), a simple database entry and a cron job should do the trick.